# Did the Autobot shuttle have a name?

Tags: transformers

In Transformers G1 continuity's (80s TV show and associated feature-length movie) "Transformers: The Movie", did the Autobot shuttle have a name? This is the shuttle where

> Brawn, Prowl, Ratchet, and Ironhide died.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The shuttle / The Autobot shuttle

---

The film's [script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/transformers.html) simply refers to it as "***the shuttle***". It doesn't appear to have a name beyond this description.

> INT. **THE SHUTTLE**
> Ironhide and Prowl sit at the controls, running a series of
> pre-launch tests.
>
> **IRONHIDE:** *Will do, Spike.*

---

The [1986 comic adaptation](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers:_The_Movie_(Marvel_comic)) refers to it as "***The Autobot shuttle***"

> [image]

And in the film's [official adaptation](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers_the_Movie_(Ladybird_adaptation)), read [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1F2XURXN7w&t=182s)

> In **the Autobot shuttle**, Prowl and Ironhide sat at the controls. Cybertron was dropping behind fast when, without warning, a section of the shuttle wall exploded under a blast of laser fire

---

In the [2006 (IDW) comic](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers:_The_Animated_Movie) it's back to being "***the shuttle***"

> [image]